# focus on newly created input field on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a form that creates fields based on input data. When a user fills in #invId, i need to create the next field #invIdDate and then focus on it.

I have tried this:

```
$(document).on('blur','#invId',function(){
    $('#invDateField').html("<input type='text' id='invDate' name='invDate' placeholder='Invoice Date'>");
           setTimeout(function(){
                $('#invDate').focus();
           }, 50);
});
```

also tried:

```
 $('body').on('blur','#invId',function(){
        $('#invDateField').html("<input type='text' id='invDate' name='invDate' placeholder='Invoice Date'>");
        $('#invDate').focus();
  });

//  note: #invDatefield is the id of a cell in table.
```

the result is when i tab off #invId, i goto chrome url field.

Comment: like Mamun said your code should work ..also You can directly use `$('#invDateField').html('.......').find('#invDate').focus();` .. but I think your problem with the id's .. id must be unique .. so if you have multiple element with the same id just the first one will work .. if this is the case you need to use classes instead

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with appended inputs, try to find it after appending it :

```
$('#invDateField').find('input').focus();
```